# Loop through two ranges

Tags: excel, vba, loops, userform, named-ranges

I need help in looping the code below through my named range or just skip blank rows.
Below code works fine until it stumbles upon a blank row.

My textboxes for this code starts at 58 and runs trough 66.
But the value from these textboxes should be pasted to cells D8:18 where D14 and D15 are empty and should be skipped.

I'm planning on expanding this code for about 150 textboxes so writing them all out is not an option.
Do anybody know a solution, it could be to skip blank rows in the range or use a named range which I couldn't get to work.

Any help is appreciated

---

Basically this checks for input in textbox, if empty then nothing happens when I press on the "save button". Otherwise the textbox value are pasted to the specified range in my spreadsheet.

The "RR2 - 50" refers to column D and row "RR2=58-(50)=8"
***D8***

**Code:**

```
Dim RR2 As Integer
For RR2 = 58 To 66
    
    If Controls("TextBox" & RR2).Value = "" Then
        Else
            Worksheets("Rabattsatser").Range("D" & RR2 - 50).Value = Controls("TextBox" & RR2).Value
        End If
        
Next RR2
```

Comment: Do you want skipping the empty **text boxes** or the empty **cells**? Then, what does "it stumbles upon a blank row" should mean? Your code should only skip the respective row, in case of an empty text box. If you want skipping the empty text boxes **and** empty cells, add `If Worksheets("Rabattsatser").Range("D" & RR2 - 50).Value <> " then` followed by `Worksheets("Rabattsatser").Range("D" & RR2 - 50).Value = Controls("TextBox" & RR2).Value`. Of course, ending the statement with `End If`...

Comment: the first IF handles blank/empty textboxes in the userform, and that works fine.

But the rows in range D8:D18 is often empty. That range is comments for data in B:B.
I´ve product titles in B7, in B8:B13 i have products. That group of title and products repeats a second time with another product title and other products. 

Between these groups, i.e. B14 & B15, theres no need for a comment and theres no textbox in my userform either.

My code should only paste textbox value to column D when cell in column B:B isnt empty/blank. My code works until B13 and then it should skip to B16

Comment: You did  not say anything in your question about values in "B:B" involvement...

Comment: Miss by me, sorry...

Comment: Did I get this right? You have around 150 textboxes on a userform or on a sheet, right? And you would like to have similar code for these 150 textboxes? If yes, the first thing that comes to my mind is _Control Arrays_

Comment: 150 textboxes in a userform. Where a user can input data and save which then sends that data to a specific range/cell.

Each textbox corresponds to one cell. And to do that manually for 150 textboxes gets nuts. The answer from "Foxfire And Burns And Burns" below works but its still gonna be about 20 or so repetitions (that´s how many times theres a blank row). but thats better than 150 repetitions.

I´m new to VBA, could u evolve on Control Arrays perhaps? :)

Comment: [Reading material](https://bettersolutions.com/excel/macros/vba-control-arrays.htm)

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is the best solution without data input, but you could handle the output of target row using SELECT CASE based on `RR2`

[Select Case statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/select-case-statement)

```
Sub test()
Dim RR2 As Integer

For RR2 = 58 To 66
    If Controls("TextBox" & RR2).Value = "" Then
        'do nothing
    Else
        Select Case RR2
            Case Is <= 63 'when rr2 is 63 or less do -50
                Worksheets("Rabattsatser").Range("D" & RR2 - 50).Value = Controls("TextBox" & RR2).Value
            Case Else 'any other case do -48. this will skip 14 and 15
                Worksheets("Rabattsatser").Range("D" & RR2 - 48).Value = Controls("TextBox" & RR2).Value
        End Select
    End If
Next RR2
End Sub
```

Notice the SELECT CASE handles wihich target row are you pasting the values from the textboxes, defining numeric ranges. You can add extra cases if you need them.

Comment: without testing this looks logically and should work. But... theres always a but...
I have about 20 instances where it needs to jump empty rows. Still, alot better than doing what i did and repeat that for 150 rows.

If theres any way to look at column B, as mentioned in comments above, and paste value from textbox if that row is not blank, then that would be optimal and just left me with a few rows of code instead of hundreds if not thousands.